# What is the suitable way of storing game data?

Tags: android, save

I'm programming a game with my own engine. I want to create a store in my game. It will be adding some new features for game with coins.

How can I store game data like coin quantity,new characters(bought or not bought)? SQlite or any other way to do this?How do professionals do it?

Comment: Use http://www.openfeint.com/ to store the data of game..

Comment: If you have lots of information use SQLite..
For game configurations use a text file.

Comment: @BBExpert I'm not intend to scores.I mean coins and other store elements quantity like in Temple Run.

Comment: @GabrielCasado Which one is more secure way of this?Game will be sale and people also can buy coins.If they can edit data,it will be terrible.

Comment: SQLite is a good way to go. There are other things you can do if you wanted to explore the possibilities, such as Serialization and Android has simple storage for key pair data structures, called shared preferences (useful for app settings etc).

Comment: You could use network connections to connect to external databases etc - but you'd have to do a bit of research on this as they are quite large topics. There are a lot of resources though as Java is pretty widespread :)

Comment: @droidmachine files should only be used for the user preference. Like, graphics preferences, sound, subtitles on/off, etc.

Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515057/android-storing-sensitive-data-in-the-sqlite-database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at the Android Dev Guide for the [data storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) topic.

Also check out [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) which is a sub section of the guide posted above.

Info on how to encrypt data in a SQLite Database:
[Android SQLCipher](https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/)
[PBKDF2](http://rtner.de/software/PBKDF2.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Which one is more secure way of this?Game will be sale and people also can buy coins.If they can edit data,it will be terrible.

Comment: then you will need to either use some kind of encryption if you store the data on the device or store the data online.

Comment: As Davos555 said, check out [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html)